# Insert XML or JSON format data from REST API call into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, json, rest

Hello and thank you in advance,

Is it possible to use REST API calls to retrieve data either in XML or JSON format from a script in SQL and then insert this data into records of a created table?

Let me be more clear with my question: The API is using REST "http://api.monitis.com/api/api.html"

Say for instance the output is as such:

```
<result>
<location id="4" name="UK1">
<row>
<cell>00:00</cell>
<cell>152</cell>
<cell>ok</cell>
</row>
```

So essentially I need to call through http REST API using the URL with parameters:

http://api.monitis.com/api?apikey=[apikey]&output=xml&version=2&action=testresult&testId=288571&day=03&month=10&year=2013&locationIds=1&timezone=-240

and then after retrieving the data I would need to be able to insert the data into a table after parsing for the data for 4 columns [location],[Time],[Response],[Status]

The process flow would be:

```
1.) Call the API with the desired parameters
2.) Serialize the XML
3.) Insert data into created table
```

Comment: Ok, could you point me in the right direction? Would I use httpwebrequest within sql then parse the data using a stored procedure?

Comment: SQL Server really doesn't have support or JSON parsing, nor for calling web services. You would be better off doing this from a front-end or middle-tier code (e.g. C# or something), getting the JSON result, parsing it, and then storing just the relevant bits into a SQL Server table

Comment: So there is no way to call a web service through T-SQL to display the results and then parse the XML and insert the records into a table through a Stored Proc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its a really bad idea, but it should be possible.

Try this article for some tips to get you started:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3821271/Calling-a-Web-Service-from-within-SQL-Server.htm

but I agree with @marc_s, this would better be done in a different tier.

Comment: Ok I agree, so lets forget about calling this through SQL, but rather through Powershell. I am having trouble with this though and receiving the error "Ampersand not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; use "&" to pass ampersand as a string."

Option Explicit 

Set oReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

url = "http://api.monitis.com/api?" & _
  "apikey=[apikey]" & _
  "output=xml&" & _
  "version=2&" & _
  "action=locations"
 
oReq.open "GET", url, False
oReq.send
 
'Response
responseText = oReq.responseText
 
Print responseText

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?